# When does $f,g \in R[x]$ relatively prime imply $f,g \in R[[x]]$ relatively prime.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Recently in some research I came to the point where the strength of my conclusion bottlenecks at my ability to precisely address this question:

*Let $R$ be a ring such that $R[[x]]$, the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $R$, is a **GCD domain** (whatever that entails for $R$).  What additional properties (if any) do $R$, $R[x]$, or $R[[x]]$ need to possess so that elements relatively prime in $R[x]$ are also still relatively prime in $R[[x]]$?*

With a little effort we can show (by way of a weak Bezout-type identity that holds for any polynomial GCD domain) that it's sufficient for $R[[x]]$ to be atomic in addition to a $GCD$ domain (hence a $UFD$) — or equivalently it is sufficient for $R$ to satisfy the $ACCP$.  This is an OK result, but I'm hoping that there's some slack here. In particular, since $R[[x]]$ a $GCD$ already implies that $R$ is Archimedean, I wonder if there's any point in the ground between Archimedean and $ACCP$ where $R$ is still structured enough for coprimeness to lift from $R[x]$ to $R[[x]]$.

And if there isn't, I'd love to better understand where the limitation is coming from!

**Update**.  If the answer below checks out, then it's indeed enough for $R$ to be Archimedean (along with being a GCD domain).

Comment: I would actually be very interested to see how your argument for the "$R[x]$ is a UFD" case goes, and especially to learn what is this "weak Bezout-type identity" you refer to. Would you mind elaborating on this point?

Comment: By 'weak Bezout-type identity' I guess I just meant that since $K[x]$ is a PID, there exists for any $f,g \in R[x]$ an $h \in R[x]$ such that $(f,g)K[x] = (h)K[x]$.  Equivalently you could say that there exists $\lambda \in R, s,t,u,v \in R[x]$ such that $fs + tg = \lambda h$ and $hu = \lambda f$, $hv = \lambda g$.  If $R[x]$ is a GCD domain then we can take $h$ here to be  $GCD(f,g)$.

Comment: Hence if $f,g$ are coprime one has $fs + tg = \lambda$.  If $f,g$ have a common factor $H$ in $R[[x]]$, then that identity shows that $\lambda$ factors in $R[[x]]$.  Looking at the constant terms of that factorization also gives a factorization in $R$. If $R[[x]]$ is a UFD, you can easily argue that $H$ must be a product of primes in $R$ and a unit in $R[[x]]$.  Since $f,g$ are coprime in $R[x]$, $H$ must be a unit in $R[[x]]$

Comment: The statement that it is sufficient for $R$ to have ACCP and $R[[x]]$ to be a GCD domain follows from the fact that for $R$ an integral domain, $R$ has ACCP iff $R[[x]]$ has ACCP, and $R$ is a UFD iff it is a GCD domain with ACCP.  The statement that $R$ is necessarily Archimedean follows because $GCD$ domains are integrally closed, and it is well known that if $R[[x]]$ is integrally closed then $R$ is Archimedean.

Comment: @MikeF thank you for calling my attention to this again.  I think I figured it out! posted an answer below, let me know what you think of the proof.

Comment: I don't really know enough to understand your proof. I see how you obtain $s,t \in R[x]$ and nonzero $\lambda \in R$ such that $fs+gt=\lambda$ (I guess Gauss's lemma is the main tool there). Then, if $H \in R[[x]]$ is a common divisor of $f,g$, you get $H \cdot (\text{something}) = \lambda$. This implies that the constant term of $H$ is nonzero and, in many familiar contexts, that is already enough to ensure that the formal series $H$ is a unit. But I guess you are after something rather more sophisticated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisiting this a year later, I think this question has a clean answer and that the sweet spot is a completely integrally closed $GCD$ domain, which means that in my original phrasing of the question (with $R[[x]]$ a GCD domain), the answer was actually *no additional properties*. I think the proof below works, please comment if you spot an error.

> **proposition**: let $R$ be a $GCD$ domain.  Then coprime polynomials in $R[x]$ remain coprime in $R[[x]]$ iff $R$ is completely integrally closed.

The forward direction is very easy.  It suffices to show that if $R$ is not archimedean, then there exist coprime polynomials in $R[x]$ which are not coprime in $R[[x]]$ (since for GCD domains, being CIC and archimedean are the same thing).
 Let $b$ be a bounded element, i.e. a nonunit such that $\bigcap_n b^nR \supseteq (c) \supsetneq (0)$.  Since $c$ is not a unit, clearly $b-x$ and $bc$ are coprime in $R$. But setting $G = \sum_n c b^n x^n \in R[[x]]$ we have $(b-x)G = bc$ so $(b-x)$ and $bc$ are not coprime in $R[[x]]$.

Now the converse.
Suppose that $f,g$ are coprime polynomials.  Since $R[x]$ is a GCD domain, there exist $s,t \in R[x]$, and a nonzero $\lambda \in R$ such that $fs + gt = \lambda$.  Suppose that $f,g$ have a common factor $H$ in $R[[x]]$.  Thus $HU = f$ and $HV = g$ for some $U,V \in R[[x]]$.   We aim to show that $H$ is a unit.

Set $Q = tV + sU$ so that $HQ = \lambda$.

This gives us the identities $\lambda U = fQ, \lambda V = gQ$.  For $F \in R[[x]]$, let $c(F)$ denote the ideal generated by the coefficients of $F$, and let $I_v = (I^{-1})^{-1}$ denote the divisorial closure of an ideal $I \subset R$.  From the Dedekind-Mertens content formula, we find that there exists an $n$ such that both $$c(f)c(Q)^n =\lambda c(Q)^{n-1}c(U)$$ $$c(g)c(Q)^n =\lambda c(Q)^{n-1}c(V)$$  From the coprimeness of $f$ and $g$ it follows, since the divisorial closure of an f.g. ideal in a GCD domain is the GCD of the generators, that $(c(f), c(g))^{-1} = (c(f), c(g))_v = R$.  Moreover since $\big(c(f), c(g)\big) \subseteq \big(c(U), c(V)\big)$ we have that $\big(c(U), c(V)\big)_v = R$.  Thus for any $q \in c(Q)$,

$$\big[\big( c(f), c(g)\big) \frac{q}{\lambda} c(Q)^{n-1} \big]_v \subseteq \big[\big( c(U), c(V)\big)  c(Q)^{n-1} \big]_v $$
so that $$\frac{q}{\lambda} \big(c(Q)^{n-1}\big)_v \subseteq \big(c(Q)^{n-1}\big)_v$$ which implies that $\frac{q}{\lambda}$ is almost integral over $R$.  If $R$ is completely integrally closed, we have thus shown that $\lambda$ divides $Q$, and $H\frac{Q}{\lambda} = 1$.  Hence $H$ is a unit.

Comment: To put this in the language of multiplicative ideal theory, I think the main idea here is that if $D$ is completely integrally closed, then $D[[x]]$ is t-linked over $D[x]$.  The proof works in pretty much the same was as above.  I don't remember seeing that mentioned in the literature but I assume it is somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if $R[[x]]$ is a PID, you can use the Bézout lemma. If $f,g\in R[[x]]$ are coprime than exist $h,k\in R[[x]]$ such that $h·f+k·g=1$ this equality holds also in $R[x]$, in this direction you don't even need again Bézout lemma (a common divisor of $f$ and $g$ in $R[x]$ would also divide $1$). I don't see any mistake in this reasoning, is there?

Comment: Certainly if $R[[x]]$ is a PID this holds, but that is already way overkill! As I mentioned above, it's enough for $R[[x]]$ to be a $UFD$.